# Смена мест между ключами и их значениями

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется словарь:

```
>>>e2f = {
...    'dog': 'chien',
...    'cat': 'chat',
...    'walrus': 'morse',
...    }
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы имена значений находились на местах ключей,
а ключи, в свою очередь, находились на местах значений, к которым они присоединены.

Пробовал сделать подобным образом:

```
>>>f2e = list(e2f.items())
>>>f2e
>>>[('dog', 'chien'), ('cat', 'chat'), ('walrus', 'morse')]
>>>for x in f2e:
...    x.reverse()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reverse'
```

И только после вспомнил, что кортежи неизменяемые :)

Посоветуйте, как быть?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Элементарно

```
{v:k for k, v in e2f.items()}
```

Comment: или так {e2f[k]: k for k in e2f}

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы поменять местами ключи и значения в словаре:

```
f2e = dict(zip(e2f.values(), e2f.keys()))
```

Если значения неуникальны, то последнее среди дубликатов выигрывает — это значит, результат может меняться в зависимости от конкретной реализации Питона и даже от запуска к запуску на некоторых версиях, так как Питон не гарантирует порядок записей для словарей (до Python 3.7)

Comment: Если что-то изменит исходный словарь между вызовами `values()` и `keys()`, в результирующем словаре не будет соответствия между ключами и значениями.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev многопоточный код это отдельный вопрос — не имеет смысла рассматривать, если вопрос специально не об этом. Что вы думаете с вашим кодом произойдёт, если словарь во время итерации изменится (RuntimeError)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, объекты возвращенные методами `values()` и `keys()` - это то что в Python 2.7 называлось [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) объектами. При изменении исходного словаря соответственно меняются и объекты возвращенные методами `values()` и `keys()`. Если изменение произошло между вызовами этих методов, ничего плохого не случится: http://ideone.com/Xgxw2B

Comment: @insolor верно что значения, возвращаемые keys()/values() в Питоне 3, аналогичны значениям viewkeys(), viewvalues() из Питона 2 (название намекает, что это дополнительный вид на словарь — поэтому изменения видны, не копия), как раз поэтому RuntimeError произойдёт, если параллельно с итерацией какой-то другой код пытается словарь изменить (считать ли возможность RuntimeError "плохим" исходом— от задачи зависит).

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя применить `reverse()` к `tuple`, зато можно сделать `reversed()` (обращенную копию):

```
dict(reversed(item) for item in e2f.items())
```

Но, конечно, применение `reversed()` для "обращения" кортежа из двух элементов - несколько избыточно.

Answer (score 0):

```
f2e={}
f2e
{}
for english, french in e2f.items():
    f2e[french]= english
f2e
{'chien': 'dog', 'chat': 'cat', 'morse': 'walrus'}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]