# Как поменять ключи со значениями в словаре?

Tags: python

Есть:

```
Text = {'in_input': 'Andry', 'in_coging': 'Tom', 'in_output': 'Andry'}
```

Нужно сделать:

```
Text = {'Andry': 'in_input','in_output', 'Tom': 'in_coging'...}
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690589/Смена-мест-между-ключами-и-их-значениями/690590#690590

Answer (score 0):

```
text = {v:k for k,v in text.items()}
```

**UPDATE:** Если нужна группировка по значениям

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

text = {k:[i[0] for i in v] for k,v in groupby(sorted(text.items()), key=itemgetter(1))}
```

Comment: Ваш код выводит `{'Andry': 'in_output', 'Tom': 'in_coging'}` вместо `{'Andry': 'in_input','in_output', 'Tom': 'in_coging'}`

Comment: Словарь не может иметь такую структуру, ваш пример приведёт к синтаксической ошибке.

Comment: Согласен, не досмотрел. Но автор вопроса по какой-то причине просит именно такую реализацию. Тогда возможно стоит для каждого ключа в качестве значения хранить не строку, а list строк

Comment: Вполне возможно. Автору стоит уточнить вопрос.